# How to reference and provide assemblies of different versions without using the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I have a project P that references two dlls say A.dll and B.dll. A.dll in turn references version 1.0.0.0 of X.dll and B.dll refences version 2.0.0.0 of X.dll. 
So when I run the code of P I need to to have both versions of X available for it. For certain reasons I don't want to GAC either. So I thought to simply put them in the bin folder, but with different file names: X.dll and X.v2.dll. However, this results in that when running P I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly X.v2.dll or one of its dependencies.
>   The located assembly´s manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference.

I take it this is due to that, when running code that pulls in A.dll which then wants to load version 1 of X, an attempt to load X.v2.dll is done prior to loading X.dll, thus throwing the exception.

Is this assumption correct? And how do you deal with the need to make available two versions of an assembly without putting them in the GAC?

(Both A.dll and B.dll, X.dll and X.v2.dll  are strongly named)

Comment: If they are all strongly-named, it should just work without the rename.  Of course you'll need to put assemblies that share a name in different folders, but as long as they are are both in the search path A and B should find the one they need.

Comment: Right, it did work by putting X.v2.dll in subfolder. And then it didn't matter if it was called X.v2.dll or X.dll, which I find strange since that suggests that it's ok for the dll's file name to be whatever, in which case I don't understand why the two dlls can't remain in the same folder with different file names.

Comment: I can't explain that, but I'm not an expert on this.